# Looking for "GAE-TaskQueues" in Asp.net

Tags: asp.net, google-app-engine

I normally works in asp.net. But recently I was testing Google App Engine and I found TaskQueues: it's very interesting and powerful. Does anyone know a similar service for asp.net?
I know MSQueue but it's not what I need. I need something like GAE TaskQueue: I put an URL in queue and the URL is triggered (based on queue config).

Answer (score 1):

TyphoonAE is using RabbitMQ to simulate the taskqueue, RabbitMQ provides a .Net client.

http://www.rabbitmq.com

Answer (score 0):

You could try Quartz.NET maybe - http://quartznet.sourceforge.net/

Answer (score 0):

[Apache ActiveMQ](http://activemq.apache.org/) from version 5.4 has a persistent scheduler built into the message broker.

http://activemq.apache.org/delay-and-schedule-message-delivery.html

ActiveMQ supports a variety of Cross Language Clients and Protocols from Java, C, C++, C#, Ruby, Perl, Python, PHP.

- You can set a message to wait with an initial delay, and then repeat delivery 10 times, waiting 10 seconds between each re-delivery
- You can also use CRON to schedule a message